# How to save dynamic html input data on postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox when you input a number it generates a table with 3 textboxes per row. Like this

[image: Dynamic input]
Here's how it is generated

```
$(function () {

$("[id*=txtNumComponentes]").keyup(function () {

    debugger
    var ComponentesTable = $('.ComponentesContainer');

    $('.ComponentesContainer > tbody').empty();
    var txt = $("[id*=txtNumComponentes]").val();

    if (txt != "" || txt != 0) {

        ComponentesTable.removeClass('componentes-table-invisible');
        var table;

        for (var i = 0; i < txt; i++) {
            table += '<tr>' +
                '<td >' +
                (i + 1) +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" runat="server" name="Componente' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" id="txtComponente' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" placeholder="Componente"/>' +
                '<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvComponente' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" ControlToValidate="Componente' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" ValidationGroup="vgInformacaoInicial" ErrorMessage="Campo necessário." /> ' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" runat="server" name="Base' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" id="txtBase' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" placeholder="Base" /></td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<div class="input-group input-group-sm">' +
                '<input type="text" runat="server" name="Comprimento' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" id="txtComprimento' +
                (i + 1) +
                '" placeholder="Comprimento" />' +
                '<div class="input-group-append">' +
                '<span class="input-group-text border border-dark text-dark"><strong>mm</strong></span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        }

        $('.ComponentesContainer > tbody').append(table);
    } else {
        ComponentesTable.addClass('componentes-table-invisible');
    }
});
});
```

and here how I read the data.

```
Componente[] comp = new Componente[req.NumComponentes];

            for (int i = 0; i < req.NumComponentes; i++)
            {
                double comprimento;
                if (double.TryParse((Request.Form["Comprimento" + (i + 1)]), out comprimento))
                {
                    comp[i] = new Componente
                    {
                        ID = (i + 1),
                        NomeComponente = Request.Form["Componente" + (i + 1)],
                        Base = Request.Form["Base" + (i + 1)],
                        Comprimento = comprimento
                    };
                }
            }

            req.Componentes = comp;
```

and the container for the dynamic input

```
<asp:Table ID="tblComponentes" runat="server" Caption="Tabela de Componentes" Width="60%" CssClass="mx-auto componentes-table-invisible ComponentesContainer table table-bordered text-center" BorderColor="#212529" BorderWidth="2" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="#eaecf1" Style="min-width: 700px;">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" CssClass="thead-dark" TableSection="TableHeader">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Width="5%" runat="server">#</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Width="25%" runat="server">Componente *</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Width="25%" runat="server">Base *</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Width="20%" runat="server">Comprimento *</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow TableSection="TableBody" runat="server">
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

My question is, when there is a postback due to validation error the content of the table will be lost and I have no idea how to get the content back cause it's all pure html.

Is there a way to retain the content of the table on postback? Pherhaps i should replace the inputs with asp textboxes?

EDIT:

It seems that the major problem is actually displaying the table after post back if i turn of javascript

Comment: you have many bugs there... this `<input type="text" runat="server" name="Componente'` have no meaning where you put it... (the `runat="server"`). From the moment you render it as html, then you get and render also the post data there

Comment: You're trying to render server-side code on the client.  This won't work.  Just render plain HTML elements on the client.  If they're in the form and have `name` attributes then they will be available in `Request.Form` on the next post to the server.  (As a personal recommendation... The more you want to use client-side logic the more you may want to investigate MVC instead of WebForms.  WebForms really likes to wrap otherwise simple HTTP interactions in layers of... stuff... which makes things unnecessarily difficult.)

Comment: Yes I had done this before with a repeater and generated asp textboxes but it was slower performance wise. The more I use webforms the more i want to avoid it's controls and use jquery and pure html but I can't switch because where I work they work with webforms.

Comment: try use something prevent post-back like update panel, just a suggestion.

Comment: there is nothing that causes postback on my form, the only situation is if client side validation fails on submit button or if user refreshes page and server side detects it and causes post back, the table won't appear